# Is there a standard term for Windows's 100-nanosecond time unit?

Tags: windows, time

There are places in Windows (or related technologies) where time is counted in 100-nanosecond units.

[`FILETIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx)

[`MFTIME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd979590(v=vs.85).aspx)

[`TimeSpan.TimeSpan(long)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz841zbz(v=vs.110).aspx)

The `TimeSpan` constructor does call these "ticks" - but since [`GetTickCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408(v=vs.85).aspx) counts milliseconds, this sounds more like a general term for short periods of time than anything specific.

I can describe these things as "100 nanosecond units", but this is a bit unwieldy when writing documentation and comments or naming variables. I can make a term up, but if there's a standard one, or even one that's just somewhat common, then I'd rather use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard term, but I have seen:

- `hns` which stands for "hundreds of nanoseconds"
- values padded out to nanoseconds (e.g., 16000 ns instead of 160 hundred-nanoseconds) or expressed as a decimal number of milliseconds (16.000 ms)
- `tick` could be appropriate, as it is typically with respect to whatever clock is in context (GetTickCount is poorly named)

Answer (score 2):

"Tick" is indeed a generic term.

- `DateTime`, `TimeSpan` and `DateTimeOffset` in .NET use 100ns ticks, as do `FILETIME`, `MFTIME` and several others from Win32 APIs.
- `Environment.TickCount` in .NET and `GetTickCount` from Win32 use 1ms ticks.
- `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` uses a tick size that varies from system to system, depending on the hardware capabilities of that system.  Its length is determined by its `Frequency` property.

In the .NET space, it would be acceptable to say "TimeSpan ticks" or "DateTime ticks" (as opposed to "Stopwatch Ticks").  If you just say "ticks", you leave it open for ambiguity.

Indeed, a very common bug you will find is improper usage of `someStopwatch.ElapsedTicks`.  The fix is a simple `.` character: `someStopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks`

Speaking generically, since there's not an [SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) for 10<sup>-7</sup>, there is no better scientifically valid term for this unit of time than "100-nanosecond units".

You *could* combine SI prefixes [hecto-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hecto-) (denoting a factor of one hundred, or 10<sup>2</sup>) and [nano-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-) (denoting one billionth, or 10<sup>−9</sup>), thus getting the term **"hectonanoseconds"**.  However, SI prefixes are not generally allowed to be combined in this way (at least according to Wikipedia and several other sources I found).

Answer (score 1):

Ticks is the right term, at least in modern C# usage (as described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx). `GetTickCount` predates that but isn't actually attempting to define a tick.

Answer (score 1):

The D programming language, which also uses this timestamp granularity (though not epoch), uses the term "hecto-nanoseconds", abbreviated as [`hnsecs`](https://dlang.org/library/core/time/hnsecs.html).

Comment: So does NTPD, the Network Time Protocol daemon; only NTPD spells it w/o the hyphen, so hectonanoseconds, and puts it in quotes.